# javascript - can we have self invoking function modules assigned to variables

Tags: javascript

Can variable be assigned self invoking function module so that the variable reference would trigger calling the function without the () operator. I want the variable to have the latest value based on the code in the function module.

the code could be

```
 count = 0
 var x = function(){ return count }();
 alert x; // should give 0
 count = 7
 alert x ; // should give 7
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use getters and setters of object properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour can be achieved via a getter, using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), for example:

```
// Add a `somemethod` property to `window`
Object.defineProperty(window, 'somemethod', {
    get: function() {
        return Math.random();
    }
});
console.log(window.somemethod);
console.log(window.somemethod); // Different value
```

Comment: What you describe in your edited question **cannot be achieved** in browser-JavaScript. Omitting parens for function calls is syntactically invalid.