# Javascript object related

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to accomplish something like this.

```
/* Code start */

  function getCurrentTime()
  {
      var date = new Date(),
      time = date.getTime();

      return time;
   }


var jsObject = {
                 "imageOne":"SomeText"+getCurrentTime(),
                 "imageTwo":"someOtherText"+getCurrentTime()
                }


setInterval(function(){
        console.log(jsObject.imageOne);

        }, 3000);
/* Code end */
```

Each time the timer is executed I need to execute getCurrentTime() and get the latest time. How do I do it?

Comment: Without parens to invoke a function, you need a getter: [Code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9691520/938089?javascript-can-we-have-self-invoking-function-modules-assigned-to-variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to execute things and get a different result each time, you basically need a function:

```
"imageOne": function() {
  return "SomeText" + getCurrentTime();
},
```

and:

```
console.log(jsObject.imageOne());
```

If really necessary, you can omit the `()` with a getter, but using a function is more straight-forward.

---

Using a getter:

```
get imageOne() {
  return "SomeText" + getCurrentTime();
},
```

This way accessing `obj.imageOne` will evaluate to a different value each time, depending on the current time.

Comment: Thx pimvdb, I tried function its working fine. I want to know if there  is any other way to do this. Because this object has lot of elements(key-value pairs) and is getting populated from some other script.

Comment: @phpsessionid: How are they populated? If they are assigned the actual time, e.g. `SomeText123456` then it's a bit tricky to replace it with another time.

Comment: Actual time is not assigned. I have a big object with lot of links to be send to analytics server. So each time when I hit the analytics server, the url should also have the latest time stamp. Links will be like 50 to 100 numbers.

Comment: @phpsessionid: I'm afraid my question still remains: how is the object populated? What values do the properties have? Can't you populate the object with functions such as the one in my answer?

Comment: Functions will work fine, I was checking if there is any way to execute the functionCalls in the object each time it is accessed.

>>how is the object populated? 
We are hardcoding the object in the JS file

Comment: I will go with functions since there is no other way to do it. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var jsObject = {
    "imageOne":"SomeText",
    "imageTwo":"someOtherText",
    getLatestByName : function (name) {
       return this[name] + getCurrentTime();
    }
};


setInterval(function(){
    console.log(jsObject.getLatestByName("imageOne"));
}, 3000);
```

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/R7JQ3/

Comment: Nemoy, this works, but the time stamp will be inbetween the text. Like 
imageTwo":"SomeText"+TIME-HERE+"Some other query parameters."

Comment: what exactly you want? are you passing the `"Some other query parameters"` from outside or is it part of your `imageTwo` property

Comment: Nemoy, what I meant is that TIME stamp can be inbetween two string. Thanks for the help, I am going to try your method also.

Comment: then use `return this[name] + getCurrentTime() + "some other string";`